# Audio file to byte array Android not getting converted correctly

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to convert audio file to the byte array, but it seems it is not getting converted correctly. I am recording sound using mic, then converting that file to byte array using file's path on the device.

The desired byte array should be like 0x12323

But it is coming like this string [B@14746f6

Below is the code to convert audio to byte array

file is the path of the file on the device. File type is amr

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (read != -1) {
                read = fis.read(buffer);
                if (read != -1)
                    out.write(buffer,0,read);
            }
            out.close();

            byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
            Log.e("byte array" ,bytes.toString());
```

Comment: `[B@14746f6` is the default type of string returned by `toString` Object method. Is not the value (bytes) of the array.

Comment: if I pass this byte array directly without converting to string then also value passed is the same

Comment: [B@14746f6 this is being passed, But I want to pass 0x14746f6 like this

Comment: I don't know what you have saved in the `file` but i know that `bytes.toString()` will not return you the single bytes saved in the array as a string.

Comment: use this, and see what is the output: `Log.e("byte array" , Arrays.toString(bytes));` your code looks good, but as EasyJoin says, you are printing it incorrectly

Comment: I recorded an audio using mic, saved using amr file format. Converted that file to byte array and then passed this byte array to api to upload data

Comment: you need to share more info about the API, what does it expect ? may be you have to encode byte array into Base64 ? your judgment could be wrong, only based on `bytes.toString()` this does not have anything to do with the actual data stored in the bytes array.

Comment: API is expecting byte array. So I am passing the converted array in the api.

Comment: @Yazan This is the value of byte array [35, 33, 65, 77, 82, 10, 60, 78, -16, -117, -78, -53, 1, -31, -24, -20, 100, -1, -25, 39, 103, 34, -128, 0, 96, 27, 38, -44, -49, -108, 0, 0, 110, -116, -28, -11, 52, 80, 60, 68, 114, 127, 70, -59, -86, 15, 5, -70, -23, 11, -111, 41, 87, -6, 69, 56, -28, 50, 34, -44, -9, 51, 47, -11, 13, 61, -57, 84, -115, -64, 60, 72, 112, -127, -74, -59, -6, 30, 97, -2, -71, 15, 119, -121, 6, -70, -86, 93, 16, 2, -59, -35, 72, 51, 79,

Comment: that's the correct output of ur byte array, as i see all is good for ur code, unless you are missing something.

Comment: But api is expecting value like this 0x22132fds and return type is byte in the api. If I remove [B@ and pass the remaining value into the api, it is passed successfully. If i pass this value [B@14746f6 as 0x14746f6 it is successfully passed

Comment: ok, `14746f6` this may look like what your API is expecting, but it does not represent the actual data in the byte array, as you can see, ur bytes array show 10s of bytes (in the log) do you think `14746f6` represents this data? no, you need to know what API want to receive , i think you need to convert each byte to hex and then send them to the API, example: hex for **35 is 3335** and for **-117 is 2d313137** so it looks like what you need for ur api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue after talking to api guy. I converted byte array to base64 string and passed it. Which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
String path= ""; // Audio File path
InputStream is= new FileInputStream(path); 
byte[] arr= readByte(is);
Log.e("byte: ",""+ Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: arr is byte array stream it worked for me, may be it help anyone else.